# SSD installed in DVD writer location or SSD installed in previous HDD location used in booting will have booting time difference?

Tags: boot, ssd, performance

**Premise:**
The idea of SSD is to minimize app opening timing and window boot time as compared to HDD.

**Machine:**
Laptop/Desktop

Many technicians in India replace HDD with SSD, and it increases the booting and app opening, and other performance speed.

Question:

1. Replacing HDD with SSD and booting with new window installation of
   the window or
2. SSD Replacing the DVD writer with the help of Caddy
   and then booting by changing BIOS priority (with a new window
   installation on SSD)

Will the latter be less effective in terms of performance for any hardware reason or any other reason?

Comment: There would likely be little or no difference.

Comment: Thanks, when you said "little" Is there anything you can share why you said "little"? I am curious.

Comment: The location has no effect why would it have? If you are talking about SATA ports on mobo they are all on the same bus just different address, I guess you are using a laptop, but forgot to mention that?

Comment: Yes, Laptop. Corrected my mistake.

Comment: Mobo means? Mobile? something else?

Comment: Mobo is gamer speak. Gamers don't have the time to write down full words. "Mobo" should probably mean "motherboard". "Mobo" is an abbreviation to avoid. Furthermore it degrades the search function of StackExchange.

Comment: It depends on whether the ports are SATA I (fast enough for DVD) or SATA II or SATA III. some laptops might only bother to put a slower speed controller at the port intended for a DVD drive and a faster one for the main HDD, or they might both be the same. Generally though any port with an SSD will be substantially faster than a HDD because it is seek times that make laptop HDDs absolutely awful. "Mobo" is a common shortening of "motherboard", the main board in your computer or laptop.

Comment: Thanks, sir, Insightful. Is there any way to check DVD writer port is SATA I or II or III?

Comment: You can do this, for example, by connecting a device and querying it which mode it runs now. The `smartctl` could see this, at least in Linux: `smartctl -i /dev/sda` ⇒ `SATA Version is:  SATA 3.2, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)`.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to look up the connection type as mentioned in a comment by Mokubai.

In case of a desktop computer compare your drive wiring to the content of a motherboard manual which might not be provided by your desktop computer manufacturer. Then simply search for the manual on the internet.
In order to learn the maker and model of your motherboard, either run msinfo32.exe from a windows command prompt or search for a label printed on your motherboard.

If you want to avoid opening your laptop so far as to be able to search for model markings on the motherboard you might rather search for tests of your laptop model.